# How to do migratiobn in django?

Tags: django, django-models

Initially I migrated one app models after that I added one field there

```
pol_id = CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
```

now if I am running makemigrations its showing me

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'pol_id' to Health without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

In my db there is no any object, I saw many answer to put there null=True, but I can't add null=True in pol_id, is there any hard migration command to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It comes out because you didn't specify default in the field. You don't have to be surprised at all.

If you don't need to specify `default` for the field in models.py, just select option number 1, and input `''` as the default value.